# Sharepoint Server 2010 Blob Cache Upper limit

Tags: sharepoint-server, blob-cache

How much is the upper limit of the blob cache from Sharepoint Server 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I believe recommended size limit is 200 GB as stated here,

> We strongly recommended limiting the size of content databases to 200
>   GB, except when the circumstances in the following rows in this table
>   apply. If you are using Remote BLOB Storage (RBS), the total volume of
>   remote BLOB storage and metadata in the content database must not
>   exceed this limit.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thank you Muhammad,
Did you know that how much is the upper limit of the blob storage from SP 2010?

Comment: @user23835 you can take 200GB as upper limit as when you will exceed it, things might will start getting wrong(which could be slow performance etc..)